# Prism WPF: How to moq the callback to return IDialogResult.Result == Buttonresult.ok

Tags: c#, wpf, moq

I want to moq the following interface:

```
public interface IDialogService
{
   void ShowDialog(string name, IDialogParameters parameters, Action<IDialogResult> callback);
}
```

I use it with the following code:

```
 protected bool AbortDeleteDialog()
    {
        bool abort= true; 
        DialogService.ShowDialog("Should xy be deleted?", [some parameters...],
            r => abort = r.Result != ButtonResult.OK);
        return abort;
    }
```

for testing purposes I want to r.Result sometimes match ButtonResult.OK and sometimes not. Is there any way to do this with MOQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [callbacks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks):

```
var mock = new Mock<IDialogService>();

mock.Setup(x => x.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IDialogParameters>(), It.IsAny<Action<IDialogResult>>())
    .Callback((string name, IDialogParameters parameters, Action<IDialogResult> callback) =>
        callback(new DialogResult(ButtonResult.Ok)));

...

thing.AbortDeleteDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was tinkering around with callback already but did not get that the newdialogaresult should be a parameter to callback, but tried to assign it o_O